# Cloudera Hue GSSError: No Kerberos credentials available

Tags: kerberos, hue

Receive multiple of the same error when logging into Hue

```
GSSError: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), 
('No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: /var/run/hue/hue_krb5_ccache)
```

`hue.ini` is configured for Kerberos

```
[[kerberos]]
    hue_keytab=/etc/security/keytabs/hue.keytab
    hue_principal=hue/_HOST@REALM

[beeswax]
    auth_username=hue
    use_sasl=true

 [hadoop]
   [[hdfs_clusters]]
     [[[default]]]
        security_enabled=true

   [[yarn_clusters]]
     [[[default]]]
       # Change this if your YARN cluster is Kerberos-secured
       security_enabled=true
```

**Hue** is running as the `hue` user and has access to the credentials cache directory and the `keytab` referenced in the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiving this error likely means the `kt_renewer` service isn't running.

This means `kinit` isn't being executed and there are no credentials stored for Hue to use.

### Credential Cache

By default Hue (4.6) caches Kerberos credentials in a file at: `/var/run/hue/hue_krb5_ccache`

To verify if any credentials have been cached you can use `klist`

```sh
klist "/var/run/hue/hue_krb5_ccache"

Ticket cache: FILE:/var/run/hue/hue_krb5_ccache
Default principal: hue/_HOST@REALM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
03/05/2020 16:06:38  03/06/2020 16:06:38  krbtgt/_HOST@REALM
```

## kt_renewer

You should also execute the renewer manually to see if it throws any errors such as permissions problems.

**Run kt_renewer**

```sh
/opt/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer
```